# Rails linked post message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, linkedin-api

I am using [linkedin](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) gem. Using this gem I am able to get profiles and connections. I am trying to update post status using add_share method getting following error

```
(403): Access to posting shares denied
```

how to add permission and use post message?

Here is the code I am using,

```
User.rb

def linkedin_client
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new(LINKEDIN_API_KEY, LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY)
  client.authorize_from_access(auth_token, auth_secret)
  client
end
...

PostsController.rb

client = current_user.linkedin_client
client.add_share({
  :title=> 'title',
  :content=>'message',
  "submitted-url" => 'url',
  "submitted-image-url" => 'logo-url'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Its my mistake, modified with correct format of add_share

```
client.add_share({:comment => "comment text",
                  :content => {
                     "title"=> "post title",
                     "description" => "description",
                     "submitted-url" => "url",
                     "submitted-image-url" => 'image url'
                   }
                 })
```